# What is the latest US Census Data I can access to?

Tags: data-request, data.gov

I am trying to find the latest census data that I can use to study US Cities.

Is [American Community Survey (ACS)](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/) the latest survey I can use?

Comment: Question is addressed here - the ACS and the PEP provide annual census summary data for cities (called 'places' in census terminology): http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7232/what-is-the-latest-census-statistics-on-us-demographics

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.census.gov/data/data-tools.html) one's the best resource..